# How I can detect collision with any shape in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to building a HTML5 canvas game so that I will need to detect collision with character with different shape.

If you have enough knowledge about this type of collision please share your knowledge

Comment: You'll probably find more help online if you search for "collision", "collusion" is something else entirely, and "collution" is nothing. (And even with the proper spelling, your question doesn't meet SO's standards).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to go with a physics engine. Somethng like:

https://brm.io/matter-js/

However, it might be overkill for a simple game. here are the basics for collision detection.

1. You know the coordinates and size of all the objects you control.
2. After each movement, get the perimeter coordinates of each object. Each object will have an array of points marking its perimeter.
3. Compare the arrays and see if the same  coordinate is present in two arrays.

This is the basic. You need a lot of enhancement to this code for a practical game. But you can figure them out after this step.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on personal preference.
One of them is Distance Detection. 
Check the distance between two objects(or coords of said object), and if its close enough, count it as hit.
You could also check overlap this way, which is a definite hit. Then just apply whatever physics you wanted to apply.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML Canvas is only in charge of displaying your "game" through a web browser. You'll need to utilize a bit of programming logic to decide what you want to render through the canvas. As far as the collision implementation, it'll depend on what you're looking to create.

We'll assume this is a 2d plane with objects moving in all directions.
Given this assumption, one implementation might be to attach positional coordinates to each object in your game, and consistently keep track of each object coordinate with a "global"  game state. You can than perform calculations on each object's position and trigger collisions between objects that meet a certain threshold.

Implementation might differ depending on what you're looking to build but [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29887/collision-detection-in-multiplayer-games) link might be useful. Hope this helps!